# Reference for Frobenius’s proof of Schur’s finite version of the Rogers - Ramanujan identities

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

In his paper “Ein Beitrag zur additiven Zahlentheorie und zur Theorie der Kettenbrüche” I. Schur has stated that Frobenius has communicated to him a simple direct proof of his finite version of the Rogers – Ramanujan identities. I could not find a reference to this proof. Does anyone know where this direct proof has been published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early history of the Rogers-Ramanujan identities is discussed by Hardy in "Ramanujan: Twelve lectures suggested by his life and work", Chelsea,
third edition, 1978. But Hardy doesn't mention Frobenius. Neither is Frobenius mentioned in Andrew V. Sills' comprehensive review http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v10i1r13 (Finite Rogers-Ramanujan Type Identities). Schur's biography http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-81-322-0767-2_14 (Issai Schur: Ramanujan’s German Contemporary) also doesn't mention Frobenius contribution, as I can judge. I suspect Frobenius proof was never published. I have no access to "Ferdinand Georg Frobenius, Gesammelte Abhandlungen, Band I - III, Springer, Berlin, 1968" (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ferdinand-Georg-Frobenius-Gesammelte-Abhandlungen/dp/B00H7GKVR2 ) to check this proposition.

Comment: I do have the collected papers of Frobenius (an extra copy which Wilhelm Magnus passed along to me decades ago).   But I also doubt that anything along this line was published formally.